# Disable onItemClickListener for one list?

Tags: android, android-listview

I've two list one with custom adapter and other with array adapter. So i want `onItemClickListener` to work with custom adapter listview and it will automatically disable when I start using same listview for array adapter. To initiate array adapter list I'm using button.

I've already try using `ListView.setClickable(false)`
. but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If setClickable(boolean) not working then u can use flag to work with as per your behavior.It'll work as u want.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onitem click event put in an if condition, that is, if its the button to enable the click then perform operations, otherwise do not.

Answer (score 0):

In the onClick of button1 set a integer flag to 1 & of button2 set flag to 2

Then define `onItemClickListener` like this

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
     if(flag ==1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You selected "+ arr.get(position)+"", 1).show();
        Intent ints= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
        ints.putExtra("pos", position);
        startActivity(ints);
       }
}
```

**NOTE:** if the flag is not 1 then dont implement the required code thus by providing a condition you manipulate the onClick of listview.